# php foreach function performance problems

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, pivot

php foreach function should send 1 SMS but it sends 2-3 for each contact. 
The code should send invitations through email and SMS. But the contacts are receiving sometimes 2 or three invitation at the same time which gets the SMS to be blocked.

```
public function handle(QRCodeEmail $mail) {
    try {
        foreach ($this->event->contacts as $eventContact) {
            if($eventContact->pivot->sent_date) {
                continue;
            }

            if($eventContact->email) {
                $mail->subject = $this->event->name;
                $mail->setEmail($eventContact->email);
                $mail->setName($eventContact->first_name . ' ' . $eventContact->last_name);
                $mail->send([
                    'name'      => $this->event->name ?? '',
                    'hostName'  => $this->event->host_name ?? '',
                    'suffix'    => $eventContact->suffix,
                    'firstName' => $eventContact->first_name,
                    'lastName'  => $eventContact->last_name,
                    'data'      => $eventContact->pivot->hash,
                ]);
            }

            \Curl::to(env('SMS_GATEWAY_URL'))
                ->withData([
                    'username' => env('SMS_GATEWAY_USERNAME'),
                    'password' => env('SMS_GATEWAY_PASSWORD'),
                    'message' => $this->generateBodyForSms($eventContact, env('INVITATION_LINK') . $eventContact->pivot->hash),
                    'numbers' => $eventContact->phone,
                    'sender' => env('SMS_GATEWAY_SENDER'),
                ])
                ->post();

            (EventsContacts::find($eventContact->pivot->id))->update([
                'sent_date' => Carbon::create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);
        }

        $this->job->delete();

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->job->delete();
        throw new \Exception($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: 2-3 emails, or SMSs, or both?  Does `$this->event->contacts` include duplicates?

Comment: Please note that your title is wrong. You question is not about performance but about your algorithmic output.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities

- Maybe you should try `array_unique` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php ) (Check the `unique_multidim_array` function posted in the comments of `array_unique`.)
- Is it possible that you have mulitple records (with distinct "primary key" with the same number ? Then store phone numbers that have already received the SMS and check against that list before sending a new one.
- Maybe your exit condition `if($eventContact->pivot->sent_date)` doesn't work as inteted.